# Using JQuery's .attr() When Selector Returns Multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I am trying to pull 2 pieces of data from each of several fields. All the fields have been given the same "name" so as to allow them to be referenced easily.

```
 <input type="text" name="common_name" data-X='ABC'>
```

The first piece of data I am pulling is their values, which does seem to be working. My issue is when I try to use `attr()`. It just stops dead in the water at that point.

```
var length = $('[name=common_name]').size();
for(var i=0; i < length; i++){
    var value = parseInt($('[name=common_name]').get(i).value); //doesn't kill the script            
    var dataX = $('[name=common_name]').get(i).attr('data-X'); //Script is killed here
 }
```

Since I'm not having issues with using `attr()` in general when the selector is selecting the element based on an id, I would think the issue has to do with the fact that in this case multiple elements are being returned by jQuery. What I am confused by is that I thought that `get(#)` is supposed to grab a specific one…in which case I don't see what the problem would be. (After all, using `get(#)` DOES work when I use `val()`).

So…why doesn't attr() work here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get) returns a dom element reference which does not have the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) method, so you can use the [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq) method which will return a jQuery object

```
var length = $('[name=common_name]').size();
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var value = parseInt($('[name=common_name]').eq(i).val()); //doesn't kill the script            
    var dataX = $('[name=common_name]').eq(i).attr('data-X'); //Script is killed here
}
```

---

The correct way to iterate over an jQuery object collection is to use the [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each) method where the callback will be invoked for each element in the jQuery collection

```
$('[name=common_name]').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var value = parseInt($this.val()); //or this.value         
    var dataX = $this.attr('data-X'); //or $this.data('X')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the html is like this

```
 <input type="text" name="common_name" data-X='ABC'>
 <input type="text" name="common_name" data-X='DEF'>
 <input type="text" name="common_name" data-X='GHI'>
```

Now the script part

```
$('input[name="common_name"]').each(function() {
     var el = $(this);
     text_val = el.val();
     data = el.attr('data-X');
     console.log(text_val);
     console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

attr is a jquery fn, should call by jquery  object

use like this

```
$('[name=common_name]').attr('data-X')
```

so try

```
dataX = $($('[name=common_name]').get(i)).attr('data-X');
```

Comment: just want to tell him attr() is not a fn of dom element, change my answer